# Flask - how to dynamically set 'checked' property to an input checkbox

Tags: python, html, jinja2

How can I dynamically add `checked` property to my input checkbox, assuming my `object` has an `active` property?

```html
{% for object in objects %}
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="id_{{object.id}}" name="checkbox" value={{object.id}}>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Adding `checked="{{object.active}}"` did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the `checked` property to your checkbox input element, you can dynamically add it like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="id_{{object.id}}" name="checkbox" value={{object.id}} {{'checked' if object.active else ''}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar situation where a simple if-else worked smoothly.

```
{% for object in objects %}
<li>
    {% if object.active: %}
        <input type="checkbox" id="id_{{object.id}}" name="checkbox" value={{object.id}} checked>
    {% else %}
        <input type="checkbox" id="id_{{object.id}}" name="checkbox" value={{object.id}}>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```